# How to clear all the jobs from Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I am using sidekiq for background tasks in Rails application. Now the numbers of jobs becomes more, so I want to clear all the jobs. I tried the following command in console

```
Sidekiq::Queue.new.clear
```

but it was giving following error.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Sidekiq::Queue
```

How do I clear all the jobs from sidekiq?

Comment: try `include 'sidekiq'` before

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire its giving TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected Module)

Comment: try `require 'sidekiq'` before

Comment: I always (really always) confuse include and require :)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

According to this issue on Github: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1732 you now need to

```
require 'sidekiq/api'
```

Answer (score 295):

You can do as it says on the [issue 1077](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1077) or as reported in this [blog at noobsippets](https://noobsnippets.wordpress.com/2014/12/24/clear-sidekiq-redis-queue/)

Both suggest we do the following, and can be done on rails console:

```
Sidekiq.redis(&:flushdb)
```

***Caution: This command will clear all redis records. I suggest not using it in production***

another approach would be

```
redis-cli --scan --pattern users: * | xargs redis-cli del
```

according to [this blog](https://rdbtools.com/blog/redis-delete-keys-matching-pattern-using-scan/)

Comment: This appears to reset my authentication on the Rails apps that I'm using (which means I have to copy cookies back into my HTTP client).  Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Hello, Brandeamon. Are you using redis to control the session of your project? Because these commands are to "clean" all data stored in redis, it is equivalent to a drop database or drop table in relational databases.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer considering its votes.

Comment: This works more predictably than `redis-cli flushdb` if you are running redis on a separate server from your rails server. I was wondering why `redis-cli flushdb` didn't work until I remembered I needed to include host and port arguments.

Comment: The problem with this approach is if you are sharing same redis/elasticache across different services, it's gonna clear all the other data in the redis db as well.

Comment: @Charles Really, but it has how to clean specific parts of the redis, I will research on the subject and post here.
But as I use this only in development, for me the solution resolves. ;)

Comment: This was the only approach that we found would work for ensuring that all recurring job changes would be picked up. We run this every time we do a build as part of our automated processes. We also have a secured mechanism for accessing this and re-daemonizing Sidekiq via one of our application's APIs (in the case of the need for a hot-reload). As far as this flushing other redis instances, we have a separate instance of redis through docker running exclusively for Sidekiq, so data contamination/loss isn't an issue for our group. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: Please add a disclaimer, this will flush redis, and clear any other keys present on the redis box

Answer (score 134):

Clear Sidekiq Jobs commands:

```
require 'sidekiq/api'

# Clear retry set    
Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.clear

# Clear scheduled jobs 
Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.clear

# Clear 'Dead' jobs statistics
Sidekiq::DeadSet.new.clear

# Clear 'Processed' and 'Failed' jobs statistics
Sidekiq::Stats.new.reset

# Clear all queues
Sidekiq::Queue.all.map(&:clear)

# Clear specific queue
stats = Sidekiq::Stats.new
stats.queues
# => {"main_queue"=>25, "my_custom_queue"=>1}
queue = Sidekiq::Queue.new('my_custom_queue')
queue.count
queue.clear
```

Comment: You can also clear all queues with `Sidekiq::Queue.all.map(&:clear)`... Useful when you sync your locale db with the prod 

Comment: Best answer ever!

Answer (score 47):

As of latest Sidekiq, just blow it up:

```
require 'sidekiq/api'

q = Sidekiq::Queue.new
q.
```

Yes, the command to clear all is literally a bomb emoji.  Also works for `Sidekiq::RetrySet`.

Or if you're no fun you can use `q.clear`

Comment: OMG, what the heck is this ? @Xavier, is there method named ., can you please guide me the doc on this method ().

Comment: @codemilan See this blog post: http://blog.honeybadger.io/how-to-clear-all-sidekiq-queues-using-the-power-of-emoji/?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=blogpost

Comment: I got `invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)` on executing `q.` :/

Comment: I love that code!

Comment: this bomb emoji made me laugh so hard.

Answer (score 26):

```
redis-cli flushdb
```

You can also use `redis-cli flushall`

Comment: The problem with this approach is if you are sharing same redis/elasticache across different services, it's gonna clear all the other data in the db as well.

Answer (score 20):

Use Rails runner in one line

```
rails runner 'Sidekiq.redis { |conn| conn.flushdb }'
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use this for clearing all the jobs

```
require 'sidekiq/api'

Sidekiq::Queue.all.each(&:clear)
```

Answer (score 14):

All Sidekiq tasks are saved in "Redis".

You can clean "Redis" by this command

```
redis-cli flushall
```

Answer (score 14):

```
require 'sidekiq/api'

Sidekiq::Queue.all.each {|x| x.clear}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete jobs from specific queues try:

```
queue = Sidekiq::Queue.new("default")
queue.each do |job|
  job.klass # => 'TestWorker'
  job.args # => ['easy']
  job.delete if job.jid == 'abcdef1234567890' || job.klass == 'TestWorker'
end
```

Read all about sidekiq and important console commands- https://medium.com/@shashwat12june/all-you-need-to-know-about-sidekiq-a4b770a71f8f

Answer (score 2):

While many ways for doing this are pretty well-documented by other answers here, `Sidekiq::Queue#clear` can't execute when you're running into `Redis::CommandError (OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'.)` When this happens, you can still individually delete records from your problem queue until there is enough memory for the clear method to work. For example, this worked for me in a Rails console:

```rb
problem_queue_name = 'my_big_queue'
queue = Sidekiq::Queue.new(problem_queue_name)
# Alternate between deleting jobs in a batch and attempting clear until it succeeds
queue.first(10000).each do |q| print('.') if q.delete end; nil
queue.clear
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized that `Sidekiq.redis { |conn| conn.flushdb }` removes all keys from the redis database. There is a safer way to clear all sidekiq queues using `redis-cli`:

```
redis-cli keys "*queue:*" | xargs redis-cli del
```

The same can be achieved with Sidekiq API (see [Ravi Prakash Singh answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56488682/3676469))